# Placing more than 8 MP4 Videos Freezes Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, html, mp4

I am going through strange problem with chrome, I am working on a web page that has 13 Mp4 Videos on page which I load using HTML5 Code as given below.

```
    <video width="900" controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="videopathhere">
    </video>
```

URL of the page is http://www.htsolutions.com/beta/company/clients, when I open this page in chrome it will show 8 video thumbnails and then it will stop loading, it won't even load other pages of the website until this page is closed.

Did any one run through this isssue? well, whatever (first eight) video thumbnails are loaded do play when clicked on them, so no problem with running the videos only problem is loading entire page, this page works fine under firefox and other browsers.

I am checking this on chrome version 48.

Regards
Manoj Soni

Answer (score 2):

It took long time, less views and no answer for me to get into the solution of the answer.

Chrome always run into issue when we use more than specific number of MP4 HTML5 videos on the page and hangs, solution for the same is not preloading the video, so my video tag changed to this.

```
<video preload="none" width="900" controls>
<source type="video/mp4" src="videopathhere">
</video>
```

Issue is resolved, I am putthing this answer for anybody who is running into the same problem.

Regards
Manoj Soni